# Как максимально быстро узнать среднее значение RGB в изображении

Tags: c#, gdi

Делаю свой `ambylight`. Устройство `arduino`. Ширину изображения делю на `72`.Высоту беру 200. У меня 72 led. Далее из каждого промежутка `50*200` я хочу получить среднее rgb, чтобы отослать его в `Serial`. **Проблема**. Проход между пикселями занимает много времени. Как ускорить этот процесс?

```
var lst= new List<Color>();
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
    var width = g.VisibleClipBounds.Width;
    var rng = Convert.ToInt32(width / 72);

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i+=rng)
    {
        int r = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0;

        int total = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
        {
            Color clr = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);

            r += clr.R;
            g += clr.G;
            b += clr.B;

            total++;
                    }
            r /= total;
            g /= total;
            b /= total;

            lst.Add(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
        }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проходите не по всем пикселам, а только по части из них (если, конечно, получение и обработка пиксельных данных сделаны оптимально)

Comment: Естественно медлено, такими вещами должна заниматься gpu, а не cpu.

Comment: Уточните, что именно медленно, `g.CopyFromScreen` может быть? Или именно итерирование по пикселям?

Comment: @Kromster пробегание по пикселям

Comment: var val = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);

Comment: @Kromster внёс правки

Comment: Не скажу за Шарп, но в Делфе на порядок быстрее работает получение указателя на строку пикселей и проход по ней со смещениями (указатель+3байта), чем каждый раз получать пиксель через геттер.

Comment: Используйте [Bitmap.LockBits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.8) и прямую работу с массивом байтов. Это работает во много раз быстрее, чем `GetPixel`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov как ответ не хотите разместить?